# OpenCV - Boundary artifacts in deconvolution

Tags: opencv, padding, artifacts, boundary

I'm a new OpenCV user and I'm working on a project for university. The program takes an input image, blurs it synthetically and, later, deblurs it. When the synthetically blurred image gets deconvolved, boundary artifacts generate because...well, so far I haven't implemented boundary conditions yet. Here're a few examples: you can see the input unblurred image, the synthethically blurred one and the final output I get:

http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/13953138566866107.png

According to the paper I'm writing the code from, boundary conditions have to be implemented via *padding the input image by the point spread function width and creating a mask that indicates which pixels are from the captured region versus from the boundary region*.

I apologize if my questions may be silly but:

**1.** How do I calculate the point spread function width? So far I use a simple 3x3 box blur kernel with 1/9s on the inside. Is 3 the width?

**2.** If the point spread function width is 3, do I have to pad the input image by adding three pixels on the four sides or do I have to pad the input image by "covering" the "dark frame" around it resulting from the blurring process? From what I understand, those "dark frame" areas contain mean values of the original unblurred image, therefore it's impossible to reconstruct the starting image doing a deconvolution in those ares, this would just generate and propagate artifacts.

What I'm trying to say is: do I have to add extra pixels to all four sides of the input image or do I have to "cover" the "dark frame", its width being the same one of the point spread function, from what I understand?

http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/13953135698274495.png

**3.** Do I have to pad the unblurred input image or the synthethically blurred one?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you provide the link to the article you use for writing you code? I've implemented convolution/deconvolution using the article: http://www.nist.gov/lispix/imlab/FFT/deblur.html there is a good totorial. Take a look also at: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/fourier_transforms/fourier.html

Comment: Sure, here it is: http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/imager/tr/2013/StochasticDeconvolution/

Comment: Thanks for interesting link, I'll try it today. If I'll get good result I'll share it here.   BTW your shared images put me to my dropbox and does not allow load anything.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Please, keep me updated.
I updated the links to my post, now you should be able to see the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the source (I've adapted to opencv) and it works perfect.

Answers on your questions:

1.Yes kernel size in this case is 3.

2.In the source on your link convolution is applied to image region
    reduced by half kernel side on each side.

[image]

Image size is equal to your souce image (all green and blue areas).

But your work area is less than whole image and marked green.

It reduced relative to source image by half kernel size (blue border).

3.No, you have not.

It seems that you have appled box filter with kernel size larger than 3.

Here is my results:

Blurred image (box filter 3x3):

[image]

Deblurred image:

[image]

You can download my source here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u11qo8o3q1a8j5f/stochastic_deconvolution_opencv.zip

You'll get [ringing](http://imaging.cs.msu.ru/en/research/ringing) on high frequency (hard edges) when using large kernels.

It can be reduced by increasing regularization coefficient (it will add some "flattnes" to image).

Here is my result for kernel from initial source:

Blurred image:

[image]

Deblurred image:

[image]

Try for your image parameters:

```
const double reg_weight     = 0.0002;   // regularizer weight
const double sigma          = 9.0;      // mutation standard deviation
const double reset_prob     = 0.005f;   // russian roulette chain reset probability
const int    num_iterations = 400;      // number of 'iterations', mostly for output
double ed                   = 0.025;     // starting deposition energy
```

For PSF:

```
const int    psf_cnt = 9;
const double psf_v[] = { 1.0/9.0, 1.0/9.0, 1.0/9.0, 1.0/9.0, 1.0/9.0, 1.0/9.0, 1.0/9.0, 1.0/9.0, 1.0/9.0 };
const int    psf_x[] = { -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
const int    psf_y[] = { -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

I've got the result as I post below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will answer more in-depth in a few minutes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I don't perfectly understand your answer at point 2. Could you please elaborate that?

Later I'm going to try your code changing the psf_x and psf_y arrays back to -4, -3, -2, -1 and so on.

I'll let you know the results. Thanks again!

Comment: Here's my source code:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105600602/sd_temp.rar

I converted the original code to object oriented. I think there is something wrong with my Mat "soluzione2", it blurs the image twice. Could you take a look at it and let me know what you think?

Comment: Actually, the final output image I get contains more ringing than the ones you get, even if I change the PSF parameters like you suggested.

Comment: It's hard for me to find a mistake in your code, sorry.

Comment: Don't worry, I understand that reading lines and lines of code can be a little boring. :)

I tried using your settings for the image parameters and this is what I got: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105600602/end.png

It is a good result indeed, but it's not identical to the one you get. Take a look at the right side of the image, for instance. I spent all the afternoon and evening double checking my code but everything seems to be ok. It makes me so nervous...

Anyway, thank you very much for all your help, you're very kind :)

Comment: About boundary conditions, let's make an example to see if I understood your reply:

1) I have an input image of 320 * 240 and the width of my blurring kernel is 3.
2) The blurred output image will still be 320 * 240 BUT the "working area" will be 320 - half the width of the kernel ( 3/2 = 1.5) and 240 - half the width of the kernel (3/2 = 1.5).
3) According to the original link I posted, all I have to do is check if the random sample is taken inside the working area or outside. If outside, I need to discard it.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105600602/boundary.png

If the random sample is taken inside the 317x237 area, it's a good sample. If it falls in the blue area, it's a bad sample. Am I right?

Comment: As I understand from paper yes, you are right. And bad samples are not taken into account in energy computation methods.

Comment: A quick update: I created a global variable "PSF_WIDTH" which is equal to 3. Whenever a random sample is generated, I use the following conditions:

`if ((sample_x.get_x() > PSF_WIDTH - 1.5) && (sample_x.get_x() < sd.immagine_input.cols - PSF_WIDTH + 0.5)
   && (sample_x.get_y() > PSF_WIDTH - 1.5) && (sample_x.get_y() < sd.immagine_input.rows - PSF_WIDTH + 0.5))`

Everything seems to work fine. When I use this condition in the "mutate" function (in the while(true) cycle) I get artifacts like these: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105600602/artifacts.png

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance!